# What is the checkbox for when editing Matrix fields?

Tags: entries, user-interface

Referring to the screenshot below; I've just added a Matrix field to a new site, and I'm not sure what the checkboxes are for? The Matrix field just has two plain text fields. As far as I can tell, checking the box does nothing, and saving the entry unticks it. Might be a bit confusing for the client; any ideas?

[image: checkboxes]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The checkboxes can be used to select multiple matrix blocks at once to apply any action to the selected group. For example, you can select three different blocks and collapse, disable, or delete all of them using the settings gear on any of the selected blocks. You can also select multiple blocks are drag them all at the same time to re-order.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, it's so you can re-order multiple blocks at once.

EDIT: Ah yes, exactly as aberkie says! They are not just for re-ordering but allowing you to make actions affect multiple blocks at once.